Not doing a mantra properly, what are the consequences and their repentance?
I was chanting the Durga 32 names without looking and after about a month I noticed that with flow I actually forgot to chant 4-6 names in between . Also sometimes while chanting the adya stotra I mispronounce some words occasionally. Will I get any partial good results for this or the entire effort will go into vain? Also is it considered a sin in the Hindu shastras?

For such mistakes one can pray to the deity and ask for forgiveness .. it is not a serious issue. Sometimes, for mispronunciations some extra japa are prescribed but that is technical and possibly part of Purascharana

@Rickross thank you for the answer. Could you guess r provide any source or texts where it is written so . I just want to accurately verify by highlighting the textbooks. Thank you.

Usually in a recital even learned persons are likely make many mistakes and for that reason after the completion of the recital Kshamapana stotram is recited .. see this Kshamapana Stotra composed by Adi Shankaracharya (https://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/durga-saptashati/aparadha-kshamapana-stotram/devi-aparadha-kshamapana-stotram.html) ...it is asking for forgiveness for all the mistakes and errors that might have been made during recital and in general for all other mistakes committed.
